# Does OkHttp reuse HTTP1/1 connections automatically?

Tags: java, performance, http, tcp, okhttp

My application has to send a lot of http requests to the same server. It may be 20 or more requests which responses should be handled as quickly as possible. In this case I want to reuse already instantiated by first request TCP connection for all next requests cause it should dramatically improve performance. While researching the topic I've found out that OkHttp has ConnectionPool where it stores reusable connections. It's led me to the question does OkHttp reuse HTTP1/1 connections or only HTTP2 and SPDY? How OkHttp api user can change this behavior?

Comment: I've found! OkHttp wiki says: 
OkHttp uses a ConnectionPool that automatically reuses HTTP/1.x connections and multiplexes HTTP/2 and SPDY connections.
https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Connections

Comment: commonly connection can be reused after response entity was been consumed

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does by default, and here is the [updated link](https://square.github.io/okhttp/connections/)